# Is it possible for objects of a class to have the same reference of a class attribute that they are in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I don't know if my question is too confusing or even correct, so to make it clear here's an example:

```
class Parent():
  def __init__(self,addr):
    self.addr = addr
    self.child1 = Child(self.addr)
    self.child2 = Child(self.addr)

class Child():
  def __init__(self,addr):
    self.addr = addr

parent = Parent('USA')
```

What I want to accomplish is whenever I change the `addr` attribute of the `Parent` object the `addr` attribute of `child1` and `child2` objects inside of `Parent` are also changed.

```
parent.child1.addr >>> 'USA'
```

But when I change the `Parent` object `Parent.child1` remains the same.

```
parent.addr = 'France'

parent.child1.addr >>> 'USA'
parent.addr >>>'France'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make `Child.addr` a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) that gets the `addr` of the parent:

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, addr):
        self.addr = addr
        self.child1 = Child(self)
        self.child2 = Child(self)


class Child:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    @property
    def addr(self):
        return self.parent.addr
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is use addr instead of self.addr in the Parent class.

Example:

```
class Parent():
  def __init__(self,addr):
    self.addr = addr
    self.child1 = Child(addr) 
    self.child2 = Child(addr) 

class Child():
  def __init__(self,addr):
    self.addr = addr

parent = Parent('USA')
```

**Output:** parent.child1.addr is 'USA'

```
parent.addr = 'France'
```

**Output:** parent.addr is 'France'